# How can I set groups of three list items to be the same height as the tallest?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three columns of text in a tabular format. They are populated from a JSON feed. How can I set every row of three LI elements to be the same height as the tallest in that row?

**Do I need jQuery or can I just use CSS?**

I want it to behave how a HTML TABLE does, but without changing the Javascript which interprets the JSON feed to make it iterate through the elements in groups of three. Thanks!

```css
ul {
  width: 600px;
}

li {
  display: block;
  width: 180px; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0; 
}

/* Makes the first cell in each row float right and the second one go left */

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}

li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is cell #1, which should appear top right</li>
  <li>Cell #2, top left</li>
  <li>Cell #3 is top centre, and will be the tallest of the cells, as it contains the most text. I would like this row to be of equal height.</li>
  <li>Cell #4, populated from the JSON feed is 2nd row right.</li>
  <li>Cell #5, 2nd row left</li>
  <li>Cell #6 should display 2nd row centre.</li>

<!-- Arbitrarily large number of LI cells to follow here, 
  in three columns, as they are populated from a JSON feed, 
  which I have not included as I feel it over-complicates a
  question about HTML, CSS and jQuery layout -->

</ul>
```

Comment: Can't you use `<div>` instead of `<ul>` and `<li>`?

Comment: I could, but the LIs are acting like DIVs anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used CSS Grid in my answer.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.container > li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top-left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.top-center {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.top-right {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.bottom-left {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.bottom-center {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.bottom-right {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

li:nth-child(6n+1), li:nth-child(6n+2), li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

li:nth-child(6n+3), li:nth-child(6n+4), li:nth-child(6n+5) {
  background: #fff; 
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="top-right">This is cell #1, which should appear top right</li>
  <li class="top-left">Cell #2, top left</li>
  <li class="top-center">Cell #3 is top centre, and will be the tallest of the cells, as it contains the most text. I would like this row to be of equal height.<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br>EQUAL HEIGHT<br></li>
  <li class="bottom-right">Cell #4, populated from the JSON feed is bottom right.</li>
  <li class="bottom-left">Cell #5, bottom left</li>
  <li class="bottom-center">Cell #6 should display bottom centre.</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

This should be dynamic enough to your JSON, it can adapt to new columns and rows and with even long content.

I created a demo JSON since you don't want to provide any.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var sampleJSON = [
  {
    firstcol: 'COL 11',
    secondcol: 'COL 21',
    thirdcol: 'COL 31'
  },
  {
    firstcol: 'COL 12',
    secondcol: 'COL 22',
    thirdcol: 'COL 32'
  },
  {
    firstcol: 'COL 13',
    secondcol: 'COL 23<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>SUPER LONG CONTENT BUT EQUAL HEIGHT<br>',
    thirdcol: 'COL 33'
  },
  {
    firstcol: 'COL 14',
    secondcol: 'COL 24',
    thirdcol: 'COL 34'
  }
  ];

  var currentRow = 1;

  for(var row of sampleJSON) {
    var currentColumn = 1;

    for(var col in row) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');

      li.style.gridColumn = currentColumn;
      li.style.gridRow = currentRow;
      li.innerHTML = row[col];

      document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(li);

      currentColumn++;
    }
    currentRow++;
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.container > li {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mytable" class="container">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the grid has an arbitrarily large number of elements populated from JSON, and there could be ten or more rows, so these classes would have to be applied dynamically which I think is too hard.

Comment: @AngusC Basically I answered the question `How can I set groups of three list items to be the same height as the tallest?` you didn't mention about dynamic contents. Maybe you can make your question clearer? As your requirement is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi David, I appreciate your hard work but please see in the original question: "I want it to behave how a HTML TABLE does, but without changing the Javascript which interprets the JSON feed to make it iterate through the elements in groups of three."

Comment: I don't see any Javascript nor I changed a Javascript.

Comment: David, I am not going to argue about this anymore. While the question explicitly says that "They are populated from a JSON feed." I didn't include the Javascript because this is a question about displaying elements in CSS, HTML and perhaps jQuery. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Then post your `JSON feed` for us to be able to answer the question correctly.

Comment: David, I have decided not to add the JSON because I believe it over-complicates the issue. However I have changed the question to help remove any possible ambiguity about what I am asking. Thanks

Comment: For three groups of elements max height. Check it out

Comment: Accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a preview of the power of the grid,

You can check the website can I use, and for be cross browser is no so bad.

[Can I use flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Here is a modification, to manage the height just use flex.

The order you can alter it with jquery. just because I guess it will be a pattern.

Let me know how did you go!

:) Happy Friday

```css
      ul {
        width: 600px;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      li {
          display: block;
          width: 33%; 
          margin: 0; 
          padding: 10px; 
          font-size: 12px;
              box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        /* Causes the text and background colours to pattern to alternate in cells */



      li:nth-child(6n+1), li:nth-child(6n+2), li:nth-child(6n+6) {
          background: #000;
          color: #fff;
        }

      li:nth-child(6n+3), li:nth-child(6n+4), li:nth-child(6n+5) {
          background: #fff; 
          color: #000;
        }

        /* Makes the first cell in each row float right and the second one go left */
```

```html
    <div id="checkerboard">

      <ul>

        <li>This is cell #1, which should appear top right</li>

        <li>Cell #2, top left</li>

        <li>Cell #3 is top centre, and will be the tallest of the cells, as it contains the most text. I would like this row to be of equal height.</li>

        <li>Cell #4, populated from the JSON feed is bottom right.</li>

        <li>Cell #5, bottom left</li>

        <li>Cell #6 should display bottom centre.</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Nestor, I very much appreciate the time and effort you put into answering this question. It is not the exact solution to my problem as there can be an arbitrarily large number of rows and cells in my table. Thanks so much though :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, change `li {display: block;}` to `li {display: table-cell;}`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @DAbuzeid - it collapses them together a bit better but it doesn't seem to make them the same height.